# How does ' data = data = ...' work in python?

Tags: python, file

The following line is from a python script for a serial bootloader. The file being read is an `.elf` file.

It seems like the line is converting the file to a binary array or something similar, but I'm confused about the `data = data = ...` part.

```
data = data = [ord(x) for x in open(options.file, 'rb').read()]
```

Can someone shed some light on how this works?

Comment: `data = data = ...` can always be replaced by `data = ...`. Doing something like `x = y = <whatever>` is equivalent to `temp = <whatever>; x = temp; y = temp; del temp`

Comment: ps, just in case it isn't immediately obvious, one of the `data = ` part is completely redundant, and this is probably a copy paste typo that slipped by

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I make this same exact copy-paste type all the time :)

Comment: Interesting. I thought it was some python syntactic sugar trick, but being a typo makes sense.

Comment: Don't get us wrong, it *is* a valid syntax, but it would have made more sense if it was `data1 = data2 = some_val`. The fact that it's the same "name" essentially means it's the same as writing `data = some_val` twice. There is no logical reason why you'd want to do that, hence it's a typo *in this particular case*